# pagination logic in calculating total of pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, pagination

I'm using a react component that need me to pass in below prop

```
<Pager 
      totalPages={10}
      currentPage={1}
/>
```

I can't figure out the calculation as in the api I have `total_items`, not `totalPages`. if I have 50 `total_items`, how can I produce 5 for the `totalPages` prop? says my limit is 10.

Comment: If you can post the pager component, that would help

Comment: @VamshiGudipati https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toolbox-additions

Comment: total_items / 10 should give you the number of pages. You also need to consider remainder of the division (total_items % 10). So total pages would be total_items / 10 and 1 more in case remainder is > 0.

Comment: @Umesh so what is the answer? are you consufed too?

Comment: My explanation is same as answered by fubar.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Divide `total_items` by `limit`, and round the value up.

```
Math.ceil(total_items/limit);

50 items / 10 per page = 5 pages
55 items / 10 per page = 6 pages
```

Comment: Returns `0` if `items < perpage`.

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi if you’re using `Math.ceil` that’s not possible, unless the number of items is 0. E.g. `Math.ceil(1/10) = 1`

Comment: For other languages that might be passing total_items as an integer you will need to convert to a float.  E.g., in Ruby `(total_items.to_f / limit).ceil`

Comment: When you desire having 1 when `total_items === 0`, you can use `Math.ceil(total_items/limit)||1`;

Answer (score 1):

integer only calculation:

```
int total_pages = total_items==0 ? 0 : (total_items - 1) / page_size + 1;
```

Answer (score -6):

you need to check if there is a quotient from the divide operation because there is apparently few items need to be showed in another page

**for example:**

```
6 items
5 limit
```

if we just `divide and ceil` we will get **1** which is incorrect because there is one item need an extra page to be counted

```
totalPages_pre = (total_items/limit)
totalPages = (search.total % page_size) == 0 ? totalPages_pre : totalPages_pre + 1
```

Comment: `Math.ceil()` does give higher number (2 in this case).

Comment: This statement is actually correct "if we just divide and ceil we will get 1", this is caused by java's integer arithmetic, Math.ceil expects a double but dividing `integer / integer` returns `integer`